# SQL Server: how do I calculate a running record count given a seed value?

Tags: sql-server-2012, cumulative-sum

I need to calculate the record count as of each record to determine when a particular record count threshold has been exceeded.

My table looks like this:

```
+------------------------+--------------+----------+----------+----------------+
|       UpdateDate       | Description  | NewValue | OldValue | CountPlusMinus |
+------------------------+--------------+----------+----------+----------------+
| 10/18/2016 09:41:55 AM | Create Donor | 48621    | NULL     |             -1 |
| 10/18/2016 09:41:55 AM | Create Donor | 48622    | NULL     |             -1 |
| 10/18/2016 09:41:55 AM | Create Donor | 48623    | NULL     |             -1 |
| 10/18/2016 09:40:40 AM | Merge Donors | NULL     | 48620    |              1 |
| 10/18/2016 09:40:37 AM | Merge Donors | NULL     | 48619    |              1 |
| 10/18/2016 09:40:37 AM | Create Donor | 48619    | NULL     |             -1 |
| 10/17/2016 10:13:44 AM | Web Donor Cr | 48618    | NULL     |             -1 |
+------------------------+--------------+----------+----------+----------------+
```

(I apologize for the mangled table view, but after 45 minutes of researching how to ask this question with proper formatting I'm forced to give up on the table format and hope you can copy and paste into Excel.)

**Scenario:**
I have a table record count as of this moment of 1,200,000 (seed value).  I need to know the moment the record count exceeded 1,000,000.

In the CountPlusMinus column I have already recorded whether that transaction caused the record count to grow or shrink. (If NewValue is NOT NULL and OldValue IS NULL, then record count grew by 1 and visa versa).  This column stores a -1 or a +1.

**Other Info:**
In Excel (when the table is small) I insert the above data, sort in **descending** order by UpdateDate and enter my seed value at the top of a new column. Then using the CountPlusMinus column I'm able to calculate when a record exceeded a particular threshold.  I now have a table that exceeds Excels' limits and I need to mimic this in SQL Server Management Studio.

BTW, I do not always have the data starting at record 1, hence the reason for working backwards from the current record count.  It's also the reason why the +1 and -1 are reversed from what you would initially think they should be.

Is this query possible to do in SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Not clear to my why the `SUM(CountPlusMinu)` would not resolve your problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: a) thanks for the formatting help.
b) SUM(CountPlusMinus) requires an aggregate, I'm looking for a running total with a starting seed value.
Does that make sense?

Comment: So you just want to know at what logical point in this data set the row count exceeded a certain seed?